# How to put specific number of trailing zeros in the scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers, scientific-notation

I want to put specific number of trailing zeros in the scientific notation.
Example-
For input numbers:

```
2e-09
9.123456e-06
2.123456789e-03
```

I want output to be as follows:

```
2.000000000e-09
9.123456000e-06
2.123456789e-03
```

Any idea how can I achieve required result?

Comment: You can try `"{:.15e}".format(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `e` format code for scientific notation, and the value following the decimal indicates how many decimal places to list.

```
>>> '{:.9e}'.format(2e-09)
'2.000000000e-09'
>>> '{:.9e}'.format(9.123456e-06)
'9.123456000e-06'
>>> '{:.9e}'.format(2.123456789e-03)
'2.123456789e-03'
```